# What is the default step in a float range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, range

In Ruby, [this](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/#bsearch) code compiles:

`(Math::PI * 6 .. Math::PI * 6.5).bsearch{|f| Math.cos(f) <= 0.5}`

What is default the step for the range in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no step in your case. Float ranges cannot be iterated.

The code

```
(Math::PI * 6 .. Math::PI * 6.5).to_a
```

[throws](http://ideone.com/WCsdgJ) a TypeError:

> TypeError: can't iterate from Float

---

Your code is valid because `bsearch` is not iterating through the range values. Instead, it is "aware" of the min and max values and halves the interval until it reaches a value for which the block `{ |f| Math.cos(f) <= 0.5 }` returns `true`.

In order to see this, you can add a `puts` statement to inspect the values attempted by `bsearch`:

```
(Math::PI * 6 .. Math::PI * 6.5).bsearch { |f| puts f; Math.cos(f) <= 0.5 }
```

Comment: The range object having `Float` limits is valid. It's not valid to iterate through it, as `to_a` does. `bsearch` goes through the range by halving the interval, not by iterating through the range.

Comment: `(Math::PI * 6 .. Math::PI * 6.5).step { |i| puts i }
18.84955592153876
19.84955592153876
=> 18.84955592153876..20.420352248333657` you can step through it though ;)

Comment: Please see the update to by answer, to be able to inspect the values attempted by `bsearch`. Binary search is an efficient search algorithm that halves the search range on each pass. Here's a more in depth explanation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: @LeoCorrea Good point. You can step through it because [the `#step` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-step) has a parameter which represents the step size, and it defaults to `1` if not specified.

Comment: With ruby 2.2.0 and this code: `class Float; def succ; next_float; end; end` you can iterate through float ranges with `each`.

Comment: @Adrian, I believe `next_float` has been provided merely as a convenience; as it appears to be equivalent to using (and is possibly implemented by) `step`, with step-size `s = 2.220446049250313e-16`: `@f = 1.0; 100_000_000.times { |i| p @f if i == 1.0e8-1; @f = @f.next_float } #=> 1.0000000222044603` and `(1.0..2.0).step(s).first(1.0e8).last #=> 1.0000000222044603`. The existence of `next_float` makes the computation of `s` easier (`s = 1.0.next_float - 1.0`) but that's beside the point.

Comment: @CarySwoveland they aren't the same, the value of `f.next_float - f` varies with `f`. For example `(2.0 ** 100.0).next_float - (2.0 ** 100.0)` is equal to `(2.0 ** 48.0)`

Comment: @Adrian, yes, they are different for large enough values. Readers may find a couple of examples helpful here: `f = 2.0**100.0 #=> 1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4e+30; f.next_float #=> 1.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7e+30; f = 2.0**200.0 #=> 1.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy3e+60; f.next_float #=> 1.yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy6e+60`. In the first (second) example, the first 15 decimal digits, denoted 'x' (denoted 'y'), are the same for the two compared numbers. The key in the definition of [Float#next_float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-nan-3F) is "representable" in "Returns the next representable floating-point number."

Comment: You say it halves the interval until it reaches a value for which `Math.cos(f) <= 0.5` is true. That is wrong. The test you show at the end prints dozens of steps for me, even though `Math.cos(f) <= 0.5` is true already at the *second* step (I modified it to print that bool instead).